# Deceiving Python's `type(f(x)) is`

Tags: python, types

There is a checker with the following code:

```
assert type(f(x)) is int
```

which I cannot change to `isinstance` or something like this.

It is necessary that `f` returns an object of a class written by me. Is there a way to deceive such a check? Something like inheriting the class from `int` or correcting a `__type__` attribute of the returned object?

Comment: If you can't change the assertion you are simply out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for a sarcasm, I have not asked you whether I'm in luck!

Comment: It's not sarcasm, sorry, it's idiom, an expression. I'll rephrase: you can't. There is no way to do this.

Comment: Is `f` called in two places? Once on that assert line, and once in real code? Can you detect which is which, and return `0` to foil the assert?

Answer (score 2):

You can always diable assert check by starting python with '-O' flag.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement

> These equivalences assume that **debug** and AssertionError refer to the built-in variables with those names. **In the current implementation, the built-in variable __debug__ is True under normal circumstances, False when optimization is requested (command line option -O).** The current code generator emits no code for an assert statement when optimization is requested at compile time. Note that it is unnecessary to include the source code for the expression that failed in the error message; it will be displayed as part of the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can offer:

```
type = lambda x: int
assert type(f(x)) is int
```

Comment: Not sure if this will cut it if the `assert` is in another module. Perhaps `othermodule.type = ...` will work though

Comment: @Eric it won't. It is stupid semi-joke answer. You can't override `type` unless as a local variable.

Comment: Not sure I agree with that. I think you can mess with the globals of another module

Comment: @Eric but it is builtin function, it doesn't even belong to module.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm confusing this with the behavior you get when `mymodule.py` contains `import math`, and another one does `import mymodule; mymodule.math.pi`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't deceive the `type()` function or the `is` operator, no.

Don't use `type()` to check for types. Use `isinstance()` and you can just subclass `int`:

```
>>> class MyType(int):
...     pass
...
>>> isinstance(MyType(), int)
True
```

or test for the [`numbers.Integral` ABC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral) and you don't even have to subclass, only *register* your type:

```
>>> from numbers import Integral
>>> isinstance(42, Integral)
True
>>> isinstance(MyType(), Integral)
True
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> isinstance(Foo(), Integral)
False
>>> Integral.register(Foo)
>>> isinstance(Foo(), Integral)
True
```

If you can't change the assertion you are simply out of luck. At most you can monkey-patch `f()` to not return your type in that module.